# How to forward usb port to guest OS using qemu

Tags: linux, usb, qemu

I have lots of usb devices and I would like to connect them to guest os. Currently I'm forwarding one device at a time.

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 ... -usbdevice host:xxxx:yyyy
```

I would like to give physical usb port to virtual machine so that any device connected to it would be forwarded to virtual machine.

Using qemu version 1.7.0